# XQuery : max of only a few data?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a XML file like this :

```
<mountain>
   <altitude>3780</altitude>
</mountain>
<mountain>
   <altitude>4355</altitude>
</mountain>
...
```

I want to get the max value, so of course I may use **max(//mountain/altitude)**, and I should get 8848 (The Everest), but some entries are wrong so at first, I only want to keep altitudes < 9000, then find the max() between all of these. How should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A predicate should do the trick:

```
max(//mountain/altitude[. lt 9000])
```

Comment: You might need to use `xs:integer(.)`. Like this `max(//mountain/altitude[xs:integer(.) lt 9000])`

Comment: That's right, if I have some decimal values I should use `xs:decimal(.)` right ?

Comment: Right, I assumed from your example that you had a schema, but if not then yes, do use a cast to whatever type you need.